# Crear 2 tablas en un concat en mi store procedure - MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure, mysql-workbench

Estoy creando un procedimiento en donde recibe como parámetro el nombre de la base de datos que se registrará en un formulario. en el primer `concat` estoy creando la base de datos con el parámetro que recibirá (el nombre de la base de datos), eso se ejecuta correctamente.

```
SET @sql = xnomBD; #Almaceno el parámetro en una variable @sql

SET @sqlCreate = concat('CREATE SCHEMA `',@sql,'`;');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlCreate;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

El problema vendría en este segundo `concat`, donde quiero crear dos tablas dentro de la base de datos que se creó en el primer concat. Lo que me parece raro es que cuando quiero crear una tabla, se ejecuta correctamente, pero cuando agrego otro `CREATE TABLE` abajo, ocurre un error.

```
SET @sqlAnex = concat('
    CREATE TABLE `',@sql,'`.`lco0001anex` (
        `al_tipanex` char(1) NOT NULL,
        `al_codanex` varchar(18) NOT NULL,
        `al_razsoc` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT "",
        `al_razsoc2` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT "",
        PRIMARY KEY (`al_tipanex`,`al_codanex`)
    );
                
    CREATE TABLE `',@sql,'`.`lco0001auxxml21` (
        `auxID` int NOT NULL,
        `auxTipo` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
        `auxAnxAux` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
        `auxNomXML` varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`auxID`)
    );
');

select @sqlAnex;
PREPARE stmt2 FROM @sqlAnex;
EXECUTE stmt2;
```

El error vendría a ser el siguiente:

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
 'CREATE TABLE `liderasoftware`.`lco0001auxxml21` ( `auxID` int NOT NULL, ' at line 9
```

Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: [Prepared Statements :: PREPARE Statement: "... The text must represent a single SQL statement, not multiple statements. ..."](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/prepare-statement/). Las consultas preparadas actualmente no permiten múltiples sentencias.

Comment: Muchas gracias, tendré que hacer dos `concat`, una para cada `create table`.

Comment: Aplica igual para MySQL: [13.5.1 PREPARE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/prepare.html).